# What are the major differences between Tesseract and AWS Textract?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, amazon-textract

I followed all the blogs and couldn't get or understand the major differences between them. Can anybody please explain ?

Answer (score 4):

Tesseract is an [OCR Open Source Engine](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract), also available to be [deployed in Lambda](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:339543757547:applications%7ETesseract), but you can install it virtually anywhere.
AWS Textract is a closed source, AI-Based OCR solution, with a [pay-per-scanned-page model](https://aws.amazon.com/textract/pricing/?nc1=h_ls), that can return in output a structured version (in JSON) of the document.

You can find more info on the available Textract APIs in [API Reference - Amazon Textract](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_Reference.html).